# Not getting the value after selecting from the list instead getting the empty value in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, routes, parameters, navigation

[1][enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB2Im.jpg)I am passing the data to the previous screen through params after selecting from the list but I am not getting the value instead getting an empty string in React native.
Here is the code:-

```
 const [text, setText] = useState({
        selectedText  : ""
    })
```

```
const {selectedText} = text
```

```
navigation.navigate({
    name: "INVENTORY_FORM",
    params: {selectedValue : selectedText} ,
    merge: true,
})

    const textSelection = (id) => {
            data.filter((item) => {
               if( item.id === id) {
                   setText((initialState) => {
                        return {
                            ...initialState,
                            selectedText : item.OrderNo
                        }
                   })
               }
```

Previous screen:-

`useEffect(() => {`
`route.params?.selectedValue`
`console.log( route.params?.selectedValue)`
`},[])`

```
<Text
    style = {{color : COLORS.black,...FONTS.body4, }}
>
    {route.params?.selectedValue === "" ? "None Selected" : route.params?.selectedValue }
</Text>
```

I have checked various ways but still getting an empty value. Please help

Answer (score 0):

To pass data back to the previous screen use navigate()

```
navigation.navigate(“PREVIOUSSCREEN”, {dataToPass: data});
```

Comment: I have also used this method still I am getting empty value